# Incapsula bot protection issue

Tags: javascript, c#

I've built a crawler in C# and I have problems with sites that uses incapsula anti-bot protection, as they're trying to execute javascript on my "browser", which doesn't work as my requests come from a desktop software.

My workaround is currently, that I add their verification cookies on my own to my webrequests, but they're changing quite frequently, so this manual work is pretty annoying.

I need to write something, that runs javascript somehow in my C# programm, so that I receive the required cookies. Any ideas?

Comment: You're looking for a headless browser.

Comment: Already using a headless browser, still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Selenium WebDriver can help you. https://www.nuget.org/profiles/selenium